# How to engage Java type button on IE with VBA

Tags: javascript, vba, internet-explorer

Can you please advise how can I initiate .click [or alternative] on "PressHERE" button on IE website [VBA]? I have tried calling it by classname, tagname and even Id which is not stated in the websites source.

```
<tr>
    <td class="center edl_checkbox" style="padding-left: 15px;">
        <input type="hidden" name="_orgSearchResultList[1].isSelected">
        <label class="edl_chb">
            <input type="checkbox" id="1" name="orgSearchResultList[1].isSelected" value="true" />
            <span></span>
        </label>
    </td>
    <td class="center">
        <a href="#" onclick="javascript:doSubmit('Edit-1');" title="PressHERE">
            PressHERE
        </a>
        <input type="hidden" id="Org1" value="PressHERE"/>
    </td>
    <td class="center" title="PressHERE">
        PressHERE
```

The specific line that is highlighted when "inspecting elements" on the site is this:

```
<td class="center"><a href="#" onclick="javascript:doSubmit('Edit-1');" title="PressHERE">PressHERE
```

Comment: What exactly is your environment (VB.net, VBA in some Office application, VBScript inside the Browser or something else)? Please show code what you have tried so far, so we can see how you get access to the HTML document in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this and let us know the feedback.

```
Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, Html As HTMLDocument
Set Html = IE.document  'consider adding this line in your script in order for `.querySelector()` to run successfully
Html.querySelector("a[title='PressHERE']").Click
```

Comment: This one worked. IE.Document.querySelector("a[title='PressHERE']").Click

Comment: That was more sensible +1

Answer (score 2):

**CSS selector:**

You could use a [CSS selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) of: `a[onclick='javascript:doSubmit('Edit-1');']` .

This says get element(s) with `a` tag that have an attribute `onclick` whose value contains `'javascript:doSubmit('Edit-1');'`

---

**CSS query:**

[image: CSS query]

---

**VBA:**

A CSS selector, for a single element, is applied via the [`.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) method of document. So you need to have an `HTMLDocument` to query. Either by the `.document` of an IE instance, when using IE to browse to the page and it has loaded, or by loading an `HTMLDocument` object with `responseText` from `HTTPrequest/WinHTTP`.

E.g. After page loaded:

```
ie.document.querySelector("a[onclick='javascript:doSubmit('Edit-1');']").Click
```

Here, `ie` is your Internet Explorer browser instance.

---

**querySelectorAll:**

I am assuming this will match a single element, or that the first is the one required. It looks pretty specific. You can use [`.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorall) method to return a `nodeList`, if there is more than one element that matches. You would then index by position (from 0) into that `nodeList` e.g.

```
.document.querySelectorAll("a[onclick='javascript:doSubmit('Edit-1');']").item(1).Click
```

or potentially,

```
.document.querySelectorAll("a[onclick='javascript:doSubmit('Edit-1');']")(1).Click
```

The 1 above is an example index which would be at position 2 in a 0 based nodeList.

Comment: I receive the answer: "Method 'querySelector' of object 'JScriptTypeInfo' failed".

Comment: It doesn't like the partial javascript line. Hang on.

Comment: Hi QHarr, thanks for help but neither worked for me, whereas SIM's line was a success. I am certain that your approach is as efficient but perhaps my inability to work with querySelector prevented me from succeeding. Cheers

Comment: I'll review in the morning. Thanks (I will respond)

Comment: No worries but kind of you to say. SIM is awesome so you are in good hands.

Comment: Hi @SIM , I have posted new (similar) question. Please feel free to take a look at it - maybe you can help.